# How does Google Mobile Friendly tool present itself to my site?

Tags: android, html, mobile

What constitutes a "mobile device" for the Google Mobile Friendly tool's purposes?  How does it present itself to the page it is testing?  Since it is an automated tool, it doesn't have a screen resolution to check for.  So, when the tool arrives at my site to test it, what do I check for to determine that it is a mobile device hitting the page, so I know to present it the mobile friendly content?﻿

Comment: Related: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/11/helping-users-find-mobile-friendly-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself by just running the tool and then looking at my IIS logfiles.

```
2016-01-31 15:37:23 23.254.211.242 GET /sliders/2.jpg - 80 - 66.249.64.198 Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+CPU+iPhone+OS+8_3+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/600.1.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/8.0+Mobile/12F70+Safari/600.1.4+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

It appears that the Mobile Friendly Tool presents itself as an iPhone, running Safari.